# Model for QF_AUFBV Query Missing the Array

Tags: z3

I have the following query (written using the SMT-LIB v1.0 standard):

```
(benchmark gametime
:status unknown
:logic QF_AUFBV
:extrafuns ((x  BitVec[32]))
:extrafuns ((a  Array[32:32]))
:extrapreds ((constraint1 ))
:extrapreds ((constraint0 ))
:formula
(flet ($x37 (and (iff constraint0 (= (select a bv0[32]) bv0[32])) (iff constraint1 (= x bv1[32]))))
(and $x37 (and constraint0 constraint1)))
)
```

(The query is a bit redundant, but it's automatically generated.)

Running this through Z3, and asking for a model, I receive the following:

```
a -> as-array[k!0]
constraint1 -> true
x -> bv1[32]
constraint0 -> true
k!0 -> {
  bv0[32] -> bv0[32]
  else -> bv0[32]
}
```

This is great, because I have values for "a" and "x", as needed. However, another query is similar, except for one small change:

```
(benchmark gametime
:status unknown
:logic QF_AUFBV
:extrafuns ((x  BitVec[32]))
:extrafuns ((a  Array[32:32]))
:extrapreds ((constraint1 ))
:extrapreds ((constraint0 ))
:formula
(flet ($x37 (and (iff constraint0 (**bvuge** (select a bv0[32]) bv0[32])) (iff constraint1 (= x bv1[32]))))
(and $x37 (and constraint0 constraint1)))
)
```

The change is highlighted: what was an equality is now a "bvuge" check. I receive the following model from Z3:

```
constraint1 -> true
x -> bv1[32]
constraint0 -> true
```

I do not have an assignment for "a" anymore. Was this intentional? Are there "default" values for variables that I should assume, if they are not present in the model? (For example, here the default value would be that the array "a" is zero everywhere.)

For what it's worth, this problem only shows up if the operation is "bvuge". Others ("bvsge", "bvugt", "bvsgt", "bvult", "bvslt", "bvule", "bvsle") seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do not have an assignment for "a" anymore. Was this intentional?

Yes this is intentional. Any value of the array will satisfy the formula.
This is because the constraint0:

```
   (bvuge (select a bv0[32]) bv0[32]))
```

is equivalent to true. Any bit-vector value is greater or equal to 0 under unsigned comparison.
So the value of 'a' is a don't care.

Comment: Ah thanks! So is there no way to "force" a value (even if arbitrary) to show up in the model?